# Failed to resolve assembly : 'Java.Interop'

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios

When I try to build the application I get an exception the following exception :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(681,3): error : Failed to resolve assembly: 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

I tried cleaning the project and building it again, also updated the Xamarin.Forms packages but still with no luck.

A little overview on the stack trace :

> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(681,3): error : Failed to resolve assembly: 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'
>   2>  Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch execution finished. (TaskId:153)
>   2>  MTouch: 2016-07-05T14:27:15.8191415+05:30 - Finished (TaskId:153)
>   2>  Output Item(s): _NativeLibrary= (TaskId:153)
>   2>Done executing task "MTouch" -- FAILED. (TaskId:153)

Has anyone received this error? I am running the latest Xamarin for Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you try to add Java.Interop.dll reference?

Comment: @jzeferino Why would I need that. It was working before. I didn't have any reference to Java.Interop.  It suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Im just suggesting it to check if it works. Did you had any external library?

Comment: @jzeferino Where do I find the Java.Interop.dll?

Comment: Java.Interop is only available in Android Project references. You can't add it in iOs. And you should have that erros related to iOS. Can you share the code with me?

Comment: @AkashAmin You have a bad reference since `Java.Interop.dll` is from `Xamarin.Android` and your error is from a `Xamarin.iOS` build. Double-check all your references and Nugets, somewhere/somehow you added an Android reference to your iOS project

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried to add Java.Interop.dll in and iOS project and you can't do it by adding a reference. Its strange.

Comment: @jzeferino I doubt it is a direct reference unless he manually edited the `.csproj`, but referenced by a library that was manually added to the project (i.e. he ref'd an Android "native" library vs the PCL or iOS version).

Comment: Got it. Thank You @SushiHangover. I don't know how but Mono.Android got referenced in my PCL and because of that it was throwing the error in iOS. I removed the reference and it's working now.

Comment: @jzeferino Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the comments above by @SushiHangover `Java.Interop.dll` is from `Xamarin.Android` and I was getting an error in `Xamarin.IOS`.

I had a reference of `Mono.Android` in PCL which is always referenced in `Xamarin.IOS` so indirectly I was referencing dll of `Xamarin.Android` to `Xamarin.IOS`. Removing the reference from PCL solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Step-by-step instructions on how to fish this one out, as it took me some time to find where the 'Android polluted' peace of code was.

1. Unload your Common code project

[image]

2. Open .csproj look for something like this

   ```
     <ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v11.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
   ```
3. Delete this segment from csproj.
4. Load the project

[image]

5. Clean and rebuild the solution having iOS as startup Project, at this point, you will get a build error that will show which `.cs` file fails to build due to missing reference.
6. Go there and move the mechanism to an Android specific project.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @AkashAmin 'Mono.Android' referenced should not be there in PCL project. 

But with this, also make sure that you have not added any 'Android' specific code in PCL project by adding 'using Android', if this was done then you need to remove this code by using 'Dependency Services', Click [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when I removed the android.mono reference from pcl project it worked fine.

I think it happens because we are building project in ios and it doesn't have any android libraries

Comment: This was my problem - I had added the reference to do some checking on the Android project in my PCL.  Once I removed all that code the error went away

Answer (score 1):

Platform specific code within the Shared Project will cause iOS compiler to attempt to use the platform specific assemblies when compiling.

In my case, I had a reference within my Shared Project's code, within the "using" statements, which was causing iOS to attempt to link to Android specific assemblies.

Removing the code from the Shared Project allowed for successful compiling of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I got this error from working with ReSharper on VS2013 (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41627).

What I did was use the Workaround to explicitly add java.interop.dll assembly to my project. This problem doesn't affect Build so you can deploy first and VS will download java.interop to your app's obj\Debug\linksrc folder, which you can reference...

Comment: I found java.interop.dll in the obj folder of the project project under test (not the test project)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your PLC project on Android link. In PLC project ctrl+f and lets go find "Android" and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above without success for this issue.
I followed these steps to fix:

1. Closed VS
2. Deleted the obj/bin folders in the common, android, and ios projects
3. Restarted VS, and did a 'Rebuild Solution' and the errors went away