# VS Xamarin build blowing up in Android DLL - unable to build - Android.dll getting IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a VS 2022 Windows Xamarin Forms application that has been working successfully on Android and UWP. I have started working with a cloud Mac service to build an iOS version. I have tweaked a couple of things the way you do when you are trying to get something new to work, but I don't know what I might have done to cause this. Obviously I know what a basic OutOfRangeException is, but I have no idea how to solve this or even really what to look for.

Perhaps the problem occurred with the VS 2022 17.3.4 update.

The problem occurs during the build, not when running my code, so I have no idea where or how to look for the problem.

I tried unloading the iOS project but the error still occurs.

Here are the complete errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.<>c__DisplayClass131_0.<AddEnvironment>g__AddEnvironmentVariable|2(String name, String value)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.AddEnvironment()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android          
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       XAGPM7006: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.<>c__DisplayClass131_0.<AddEnvironment>g__AddEnvironmentVariable|2(String name, String value)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.AddEnvironment()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17         0
```

and here is what might be the relevant code from Xamarin.Android.Common.targets

```
<Target Name="_GeneratePackageManagerJava"
  DependsOnTargets="$(_GeneratePackageManagerJavaDependsOn)"
  Inputs="@(_AndroidMSBuildAllProjects);$(_ResolvedUserAssembliesHashFile);$(MSBuildProjectFile);$(_AndroidBuildPropertiesCache);@(AndroidEnvironment);@(LibraryEnvironments)"
  Outputs="$(_AndroidStampDirectory)_GeneratePackageManagerJava.stamp">
  <!-- Create java needed for Mono runtime -->
  <GeneratePackageManagerJava
    ResolvedAssemblies="@(_ResolvedAssemblies)"
    ResolvedUserAssemblies="@(_ResolvedUserAssemblies)"
    SatelliteAssemblies="@(_AndroidResolvedSatellitePaths)"
    NativeLibraries="@(AndroidNativeLibrary);@(EmbeddedNativeLibrary);@(FrameworkNativeLibrary)"
    MonoComponents="@(_MonoComponent)"
    MainAssembly="$(TargetPath)"
    OutputDirectory="$(_AndroidIntermediateJavaSourceDirectory)mono"
    EnvironmentOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
    Manifest="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
    Environments="@(AndroidEnvironment);@(LibraryEnvironments)"
    AndroidAotMode="$(AndroidAotMode)"
    AndroidAotEnableLazyLoad="$(AndroidAotEnableLazyLoad)"
    EnableLLVM="$(EnableLLVM)"
    HttpClientHandlerType="$(AndroidHttpClientHandlerType)"
    TlsProvider="$(AndroidTlsProvider)"
    Debug="$(AndroidIncludeDebugSymbols)"
    AndroidSequencePointsMode="$(_SequencePointsMode)"
    EnableSGenConcurrent="$(AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent)"
    IsBundledApplication="$(BundleAssemblies)"
    SupportedAbis="@(_BuildTargetAbis)"
    AndroidPackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)"
    EnablePreloadAssembliesDefault="$(_AndroidEnablePreloadAssembliesDefault)"
    PackageNamingPolicy="$(AndroidPackageNamingPolicy)"
    BoundExceptionType="$(AndroidBoundExceptionType)"
    InstantRunEnabled="$(_InstantRunEnabled)"
    RuntimeConfigBinFilePath="$(_BinaryRuntimeConfigPath)"
    UsingAndroidNETSdk="$(UsingAndroidNETSdk)"
    UseAssemblyStore="$(AndroidUseAssemblyStore)"
  >
    <Output TaskParameter="BuildId" PropertyName="_XamarinBuildId" />
  </GeneratePackageManagerJava>
  <Touch Files="$(_AndroidStampDirectory)_GeneratePackageManagerJava.stamp" AlwaysCreate="True" />
  <WriteLinesToFile
      File="$(_AndroidBuildIdFile)"
      Lines="$(_XamarinBuildId)"
      Overwrite="true"
      WriteOnlyWhenDifferent="true"
  />
```

Just in case anyone doubts that this is a build-time problem, here is 100% of the build output, unedited:

```
Rebuild started...
Restored C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2\KhyberPassWithUWP2.csproj (in 35 ms).
Restored C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android\KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android.csproj (in 297 ms).
Restored C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP\KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP.csproj (in 902 ms).
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: KhyberPassWithUWP2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2\AppShell.xaml.cs(35,27,35,39): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
1>C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2\Views\Sharing.xaml.cs(152,99,152,101): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
1>KhyberPassWithUWP2 -> C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\KhyberPassWithUWP2.dll
1>Done building project "KhyberPassWithUWP2.csproj".
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
3>  KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP -> C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP\bin\x86\Debug\KhyberPassWithUWP2.UWP.exe
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2733,5): warning APPX0108: The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478.
2>C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android\AuthenticationAndroid.cs(32,68,32,93): warning CS0612: 'AuthenticationAndroid.CheckFingerprintAvailable()' is obsolete
2>  KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android -> C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\KhyberPass 2022\KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android\bin\Debug\KhyberPassWithUWP2.Android.dll
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1683,3): error XAGPM7006: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1683,3): error XAGPM7006:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.<>c__DisplayClass131_0.<AddEnvironment>g__AddEnvironmentVariable|2(String name, String value)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1683,3): error XAGPM7006:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.AddEnvironment()
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1683,3): error XAGPM7006:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GeneratePackageManagerJava.RunTask()
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1683,3): error XAGPM7006:    at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Could you provide some C# code related to `GeneratePackageManagerJava`, if there is ? And you can also check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-6.0) about `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: I have no idea where the underlying C# or ??? code might be. The only <GeneratePackageManagerJava> in the solution is the snippet I posted above. And as I said, I totally "get" IndexOutOfRangeException. If it were my array and my subscript I would not be asking here.

Comment: Consider starting working with a cloud Mac service, you can run it natively on the machine. And see if there will be a problem.

Comment: As I say in the OP, I *am* working with a cloud Mac service.

And the problem is in the Android project. It occurs even if I unload the iOS project, as I say in the OP,

Comment: Have you ever run it natively, Mac instead of cloud Mac service ?

Comment: No. #1 I am just starting on the iOS version. I have never attempted to run it anywhere. #2. The problem is at BUILD TIME, not run time. I cannot build the project anymore. #3 The problem is with the Android project. It happens even with the IOS project unloaded.

Comment: Could you provide some basic code so that I can reproduce your situation.

Comment: @Charles Can you create a sample project on Git or somewhere else in which I can reproduce your issue? Or give us some kind of a starting point because as you say this is a compile-time error and not a runtime error which, to begin with, is confusing to me since I have never seen an array throw Index out of range at compile time..

Comment: I have no idea what code causes this. Posted above is much of the code. The error is occurring apparently in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets, which is a Visual Studio file. Trust me, the error is occurring on a build.

Comment: I just edited into the OP 100% of the build output so that you can clearly see that it is a BUILD-TIME problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The original issue was that the Xamarin project as set up by the VS Wizard had a reference to Mono.Android at the solution level. That obviously is not right for an iOS build. Searching the Web for an answer I found [Failed to resolve assembly : 'Java.Interop'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199278/failed-to-resolve-assembly-java-interop). I followed the upvoted answer there and I must have somehow hosed up the .csproj files in some subtle way. I restored the .cscproj files from an archival backup and the problem has gone away. I fixed the Mono.Android reference from within VS rather than by hacking on .csproj as the answer above suggested.